# Python tornado redirect issue

Tags: python, redirect, tornado

I am trying to redirect to a URL after loading my index.html. The html does a get on http://localhost:8000/login and it gives a COR error like so:

'Failed to load http://example.com/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.'

Here is the relevant snippet, what am I missing?

```
 R_URL=http://example.com
 class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def set_default_headers(self):
       print("setting headers!!!")
       self.set_header("access-control-allow-origin", "*")
       self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
       self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
       self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", R_URL)
       self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "access-control-allow-origin,authorization,content-type")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that you, in my case i solved adding this header:

```
self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    "Authorization, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, X-Requested-By, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control")
```

I hope have help you.